# mySQL form and report front end (non adminastrative and not for web)

Tags: mysql, forms, report, frontend, production-environment

I'm searching for software in which I can make forms and reports for MySQL database, similar as with MS Access.

It's intented use is in a production environment to create a DB with a front end for all the data that can/is not allowed to be stored in the ERP system.

The problem I'm having is when searching for front end software most of the time it is

```
Administrated GUI's or
Web GUI's
```

What I need is somthing I can use as easiliy as MS access in a local factory environment.

We did already test MS access but it was to slow when running queries to fill the forms (and I see also a lot of downsides when MS access is combined with MySQL)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at LibreOffice Base? It is an Access-like front end to MySQL for forms, reports, etc.